# How can i transfer my mercurial repo from rhodecode to bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, rhodecode

I have my reposerver on `rhodecode`.

IN my repo i have `1000 commits`.

Now i want to export my that `mercurial` repo to bit bucket with all those 1000 commits so that i can go to any previous revision to see code chnage

i can export one revision but i don't know how to push all 100 commits with all messages etc

thanks

Comment: @PaulS the answer which is given does not answer what i want. it just shows how to push repo , not the entire commits

Comment: Every clone of a repo contains all of the changesets (commits). This is a fundamental truth of mercurial. Cloning from one place and pushing to another will copy everything.